# Why Splash headless browser can not able to fetch the page of Linkedin

Tags: headless-browser, scrapy-splash, scrapinghub, splash-js-render

I have tried to get the page source of Linkedin. But I cannot able to fetch even for one URL. I got the response like "Failed loading page"

Few samples,
https://www.linkedin.com/company/amazon
https://www.linkedin.com/company/apple

Splash version: 3.4
OS: Ubuntu

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Please, indicate which Splash parameters you used, preferably through a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and consider indicating what makes your question different from [existing questions about Splash and LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsplash-js-render%5D+linkedin).